# How does one configure puppet for push-only updates?

Tags: puppet, configuration-management

Setting `runinterval=0` in `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` causes continuous pulls, not no pulls.  I'm trying to arrange puppet so that it will listen for `puppetrun` calls, but never pull without one.

Comment: What did you do in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Run `puppetd` with `--no-client` option and it will just wait for the master to initiate an update.

From `man puppetd`:

```
no-client: Do not create a config client. This will cause the daemon
           to run without ever checking for its configuration automatically,
           and only makes sense when used in conjunction with --listen.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run `puppetd` with the `--onetime` option, and don't start it from `init.d` or `cron`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to preserve the ability to use puppetrun from the server to deliver pushes.

Comment: As an additional note, setting runinterval to an absurdly huge number (say, ten years worth) works for preventing pulls after the daemon is running, but a pull will still always be started as the daemon starts.  If there's any way to just prevent that initial run, that would probably solve my problem as well.